# Ruby, pluck on hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

s is hashes of array

```
relativebase = s.pluck(:base_point).inject(:+) + s.pluck(:distance_point).inject(:+) + s.pluck(:speed_point).inject(:+) + s.pluck(:frequency_point).inject(:+) + s.pluck(:quality_point).inject(:+)
```

This is calling the database four times which I want to do in one single query. How can i get this.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 [supports](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) multiple names in `pluck`:

```
relativebase = s.pluck(:base_point, 
                       :distance_point,
                       :speed_point,
                       :frequency_point).inject(0) do |sum, (bp, dp, sp, fp)|
                  sum + bp + dp + sp + fp
               end
```

Actually I personally think that it is probably better to calculate the sum in the database, but I'm not sure how to do that elegantly in rails:

```
SELECT SUM(base_point + distance_point + speed_point + frequency_point) FROM s
```

Comment: We can achieve by this way also s.sum(:base_point) + s.sum(:distance_point)+.......but again it calls database four times which I want to reduce in a single call. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

`User.select(:a, :b, :c, :d).all.inject([]) { |res, e| res << e.a; res << e.b; res << e.c; res << e.d; res }`

Comment: When you will be having multiple lines, then use `do..end` block style

Comment: We can achieve by this way also s.sum(:base_point) + s.sum(:distance_point)+.......but again it calls database four times which I want to reduce in a single call. Thanks in advance